# Cannot upgrade from ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade

When running `sudo do-release-upgrade` I eventually get an error

```
Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If 
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in 
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. 
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.
```

In `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log` I see the following

```
2022-09-10 19:16:11,956 DEBUG Marking 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade
2022-09-10 19:16:12,108 WARNING Can't mark 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
2022-09-10 19:16:12,350 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'Broken packages after upgrade: ubuntu-desktop'
```

However I can't find any held broken packages. `sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` is empty.

Running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` does not reveal anything strange

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: It is saying you have broken packages. To upgrade you must be current & have no errors. So you need to resolve those first. You also need to remove any ppas & proprietary drivers like nVidia. You reinstall those after upgrade. Do `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` If errors, run any repair commands it suggests.

Comment: Please include the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: That does not answer my question. I have included the output of `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` in my question. It looks fine...

Comment: It says "broken packages *after* upgrade", not before. Remove the external repos before upgrading, preferably with `ppa-purge`.

Comment: I removed them. Still same error

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit of trial-and-error, and going through the /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log, it was fairly obvious that the problem was caused primarily by the Python 3.10 package (and its dependencies), and a couple of other installed applications (like Zoom). After removing these packages (I used the Synaptic Package Manager), the upgrade went through smoothly.